# Play swf in background

Tags: javascript, html, audio, background, swfobject

**Some Background:**

Basically i'm building a remote monitoring system that reads data from an XML file on a piece of hardware running a web server. Its currently only capable of html and cgi requests and runs basic javascript. Its just not got php built into it!

I have got the whole thing set up and doing what I want it to do apart from the last step now!
When an input is triggered, the xml file changes, which in turn is changing the color of an text element on the site using the

```
document.getElementById('btn' + i).style.color = '#d00';
```

i also have a innerHTML changing with this as well:

```
document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = '&bull; ALERT ' + getXMLValue(xmlData, 'inputname'+i) + '<object width="1" height="1"><param name="movie" value="http://www.upsenergy.co.uk/beep.swf"><embed src="http://www.upsenergy.co.uk/beep.swf" width="1" height="1"></embed></object>';
```

which play the swf sound when an input is triggered which is working fine, well, as long as the tab is selected! which means i have to have the monitoring webpage in front of anything and selected to have the sound play.

**What im asking is:**

Is there a way of having the sound play in the background even if a tab isn't selected?

Is this a browser thing, or a coding thing? I've seen countless adds manage this with no problem at all!

Comment: There's an example here: http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/  - controlling a flash movie using standard html buttons + javascript

Comment: @marc-b so with this i'd just add the movie using the innerHTML then add a play function after it?

Comment: No, you'd embed the movie regardless so it's loaded and ready. then use the JS code to tell the movie to play itself, which'd give you your beep sound.

Comment: @marc-b so add it into it like document.getElementById('btn' + i).innerHTML = '&bull; ALERT ' + getXMLValue(xmlData, 'inputname'+i) + flashMovie.Play();

Comment: that makes no sense. adding the results of a .play() call to the innerhtml of a button?

Comment: @MarcB the 'btn' is the name of some link text. i would need to use it like document.getElementById('myFlashMovie').flashMovie.Play();

Comment: That's fine, but you're doing `button.innerHTML = Play()`. that doesn't make clicking the button call the play function. you'd need to change the button's onclick.

Comment: @MarcB i'm trying to do this without a button. the xml document is refreshed every 500ms like so: setTimeout("newAJAXCommand('status.xml', updateStatus, true)",500); so the data is current. If the xml data is read as for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) { if(getXMLValue(xmlData, 'input'+i) == '1')
This then changes the inputs to red if they are switched on on the hardware, i can show you an online demo if you would like?

Comment: @MarcB http://pastebin.com/UfbC7NuG